# How to remove spacing between div and window

Tags: html, css

I made a div with a 2 buttons but there is space between it and the screen/window. I have seen this fixed before but I cannot remember how it was fixed, so any help would be good! Thanks.

The image (https://ibb.co/gcTD9G).

Comment: can you show the css and html?

Comment: I guess setting background as transparent to the buttons' container should be enough

Comment: I looked at the answer and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `margin: 0` for both `body` and your `div` :

```
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div {
    margin: 0;
}
```

If you post your code we can help you more!

Comment: No need, this helped thank you so much!